# Valores vacíos SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta que me arroja un valor vacío y cuando intento realizar un case para quitar ese valor nulo, el resultado siempre me sale nada:

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN (tfa3.[Requerimientos] = '' OR tfa3.[Requerimientos] IS NULL)  THEN 'No se Encontro Informacion'
WHEN tfa3.[Requerimientos] <> '' THEN tfa3.[Requerimientos]
END AS [Requerimientos]
FROM #TablaFormato tfa3
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe otra forma de manejar o validar valores vacíos.

Comment: Los case se validan secuenciales. Si cae en un caso no excluye que caiga en el siguiente. Piensa en el switch-case de otros lenguajes

Comment: si lo que necesitas es un operador OR o AND no debes anidar los when, puedes operar distintos operadores en el mismo criterio. primero consultas si es vacío y luego si esta entre que +- vacio en lógica si es verdadero es verdadero y el siguiente por default es falso, por lo tanto si no esta vacío esta en el rango mayor menor vacio.

Comment: Hola Marco, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Comment: Lo que muestras es que no hay filas. Si no hay filas, no se puede evaluar la expresión CASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
select ISNULL(tfa3.[Requerimientos], 'No se encontró información') as Requerimientos
from #TablaFormato tfa3;
```

Aquí se hace uso de la **función ISNULL**, esta función tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
ISNULL(expression, value)
```

Esta función evalúa el **parámetro expression** y de no ser nulo pues retorna el propio **parámetro expresión**, en caso de ser nulo se retorna el **parámetro valor**.

Comment: Pero eso no considera las cadenas vacias